# Не получается подключить Google Maps в android-приложение

Tags: android, android-studio

Вставил через функции Android Studio активность и layout для Google Maps. Их содержи`

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}}`
```

И вот:

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.navigation.MapsActivity" />
```

Прописал API-ключ в созданном файлике "google_maps_api".
Отредактировал gradle-файл:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

А также файл манифеста:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

И

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activities.navigation.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"> </activity>
```

Однако при открытии этой активности возникает в логах ошибка:

> E/EGL_adreno: CreateContext rcMajorVersion:1, minorVersion:0
>                 rcCreateContext returned 0
>                 tid 3923: eglCreateContext(1532): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1884
>                     Process: ru.odosenok.oskolcity, PID: 3760
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: 12291
>                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ba.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12688013@12.6.88 (020700-197970725):29)
>                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12688013@12.6.88 (020700-197970725):132)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3760 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так? Уже третий день с этим разбираюсь, делал по множеству уроков эти карты. Уже вплоть до того, что взял подготовленную разработчиками Android Studio, но она все равно не работает..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425635/egl-error-when-trying-to-run-mapsactivity-on-android-emulator

Comment: Да, действительно, проблема оказалась в эмуляторе. Не стал ковыряться в его настройках, перешел на реальное устройство. Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Рад был помочь:)